# Accessing the windows admin shares when not connected to a network

Tags: windows-xp

I'm finding that I can't access the admin shares on an XP64 box when there's no network connection. Trying to browse to `\\localhost\c$` fails (although obviously browsing `c:` works).

Reason for the question is that the NANT build script for our application uses this format to copy files from one local directory to another, and it's failing when I'm trying to use my laptop on the train (the same problem occurs if I unplug the network cable from my desktop and build). The whole build only uses local resources so should be possible without network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install a loopback adapter to fool the computer into thinking it's on a network. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013